# Proper approach with flutter bloc and state initializing

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have multiple flutter blocs/cubit in my application for example authentication_bloc, user_bloc, theme_bloc, and so on. In every bloc, there is a common state that is initializing state for example AuthInitializingState, UserInitializingState, or ThemeInitializingState... So in main.dart I have to check for every initializing state to show a splash/loading screen. `if authState is AuthInitializingState || userState is UserInitializing state || .....{//show splash/loading screen}` my question is - is there any better way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 3 different bloc's states result in same state, then most probably you might handling the state wrong.

`AuthState` should be the parent of all the states, in most cases, based on the auth state, the `UserState` and `ThemeState` gets affected. What we usually should do is having the `AuthState` as a global state and only if the `AuthBloc` emits `SuccessState`, we usually instantiate `UserBloc`. That way, the `UserBloc` starts with initial state.

In your case, I think, it would be better to have `ThemeBloc` and `AuthBloc` as global blocs and `UserBloc` as child bloc if Auth state succeeds.

Hope it helps!